# changing alpha-channel of select-pixels of image using numpy

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, alpha-transparency

Relatively new to numpy - trying to use it for image-processing; I have an image in the RGBA color-space; the image is mostly transparent w/ a small-object whose transparency I want to change from 255 to 127, without affecting the transparency of surrounding pixels whose alpha is 0. I can index into the array and find all the groups of pixels I want, but am struggling on how to actually change their alpha-channels to 127 w/o affecting the alpha-channels of all the pixels; here is how I am indexing into the array - the things I've tried either do not affect the array or else reassign all the alphas in the entire array to 127:

```
>>> from PIL import Image
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = Image.open('a.png')
>>> b = np.array(a)
>>> b.shape
(1080, 1080, 4)
>>> b[b[:,:,3]==255][:,3]
array([255, 255, 255, ..., 255, 255, 255], dtype=uint8)
>>> b[b[:,:,3]==255][:,3] = 127
>>> b[b[:,:,3]==255][:,3]
array([255, 255, 255, ..., 255, 255, 255], dtype=uint8)
```

Solution:

```
>>> b[540,540]
array([  0,   0,   0, 255], dtype=uint8)
>>> alpha = b[:,:,3]
>>> b[alpha==255,3]=127
>>> b[540,540]
array([  0,   0,   0, 127], dtype=uint8)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because double slicing the array will produce a view of the copy of the array. That's why your array will not be updated. Instead, you can put it together in one slice.

```
b[b[:,:,3]==255,3] = 127
```

Comment: thanks for the response, I tried your way, but it still does not seem to be changing the values from 255 to 127 - I put the code in my original-answer.

Comment: You wish to change only the particular value to 127, or the array to 127?

Comment: I want to change only the particular value, the alpha value, which is the last value, so that each pixel, eg (r,g,b,a), the a(lpha) changes from 255 to an arbitrary-value.

Comment: Sort of, I don't want all values that are 255 to be changed to 127, only those values in the alpha-index that are 255 to be changed to 127...the shape of my array is (1080,1080,4), indices 0-2 are for red, green and blue-channels, I want those kept as is, just index 3 (of axis 2) to be changed if they are 255.

Comment: I have updated it, this should work now

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like this. I am actually changing 128 to 255 because it's easier to display:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

# Make solid red image
im = np.full((100,300,4), [255,0,0,255], np.uint8)

im[20:80, 20:80,   3] =  64  # 25% opaque square on left
im[20:80, 120:180, 3] = 128  # 50% opaque square in centre
im[20:80, 220:280, 3] = 192  # 75% opaque square on right

Image.fromarray(im).save('start.png')
```

[image]

```
# Now define easy way to refer to alpha channel
alpha = im[:, :, 3]

# Anywhere alpha is 128, change it to 255
alpha[alpha==128] = 255

Image.fromarray(im).save('result.png')
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for the response, I combined your answer w/ the other one in the solution.